# Merge very large csv using pandas or awk

Tags: pandas, join, awk

I have 2 csv as below (tried to read them through pandas) df1 file is 17GB (i read it through pandas read_csv) , df2 is 700mb, I want to merge using `trig_seq`. But python gets killed. Is there a way to do it through awk/join

```
>>> df1.head()
   StreamId  SeqNum        Timestamp_p1     trig_seq
         1       1                14914503  10000000001
         1       2                  1491450  10000000002
         1       3                   1491450 10000000003
         1       4                  1491450  10000000004
         1       5                    149145  10000000005
>>> df2= pd.read_csv("/tmp/my.csv")
>>> df2.head()
     model_id  order               ctime     trig_seq
         e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
         e62  1000001  149199641344  30021210134
          e22   1000002  1491081210880  30021227875
           e62   1000003  14951949824  30021239627
           e62   1000004  14927136256  30021241522
>>> r1 = pd.merge(df1,df2)
Killed
```

Comment: how should look the final result for the above input?

Comment: df2 (smaller file) should just have 1 extra column of timestamp_p1 from df1. Which it mapped using` trig_seq`

Comment: Are the rows that match unique in `df1`, for instance you want to just merge timestamp from `df1` to `df2`, so you want to filter `df1` by the `trig_seq` that matches, so are these matches unique and non-repeating so `df1` say has 1 million unique trig_seq and `df2` contains a subset of this

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat f1
         1       1                14914503  10000000001
         1       2                  1491450  10000000002
         1       3                   1491450 10000000003
         1       4                  1491450  10000000004
         1       5                    149145  10000000005
$ cat f2
         e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
         e62  1000001  149199641344  30021210134
          e22   1000002  1491081210880  30021227875
           e62   1000003  14951949824  30021239627
           e62   1000004  14927136256  30021241522
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} $2 in a {print $0,a[$1]}' f2 f1|column -t
1  1  14914503  10000000001  e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
1  2  1491450   10000000002  e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
1  3  1491450   10000000003  e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
1  4  1491450   10000000004  e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
1  5  149145    10000000005  e62  1000000  1493311414272  30021182183
```

Answer (score 0):

basicaly

```
awk 'FNR=NR{T[$4]=$3;next}{print $0 OFS T[$2]}' f1 f2 > New.f2
```

if memory problem occur, try this that load only needed timestamp but read twice f2

```
awk 'FNR==1 { f++ }
  f==1 { T[$2]; next }
  f==2 && ($4 in T) { T[$4]=$3; next }
  { print $0 OFS t[$2] }
  ' f2 f1 f2 > New.f2
```